# Entity Framework strange migration on relationship change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relation

I have two models

```
  public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Active = true;
        }

        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public List<Service> Services { get; set; }

        public List<SubService> SubServices { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<long> ServiceIds { get; set; }

        public bool IsSyncedToSP { get; set; }

        public Certificate Certificate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<long> SubServiceIds { get; set; }

        public List<long> GetServiceIds()
        {
            if (ServiceIds != null && ServiceIds.Count > 0)
            {
                return ServiceIds;
            }
            else if (Services != null && Services.Count > 0)
            {
                return Services.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
            }
            return new List<long>();
        }
```

and

```
public class Certificate
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UnsyncOnEdit(Unsync = true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsSyncedToSP { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add `public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` this relation to certificate model and try to add migration, 
EF creates following migration

```
 public partial class empcert2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.ServiceClients", newName: "ClientServices");
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.EmployeeServices", newName: "ServiceEmployees");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ClientServices");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ServiceEmployees");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ClientServices", new[] { "Client_Id", "Service_Id" });
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ServiceEmployees", new[] { "Service_Id", "Employee_Id" });
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ServiceEmployees");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ClientServices");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ServiceEmployees", new[] { "Employee_Id", "Service_Id" });
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ClientServices", new[] { "Service_Id", "Client_Id" });
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.ServiceEmployees", newName: "EmployeeServices");
            RenameTable(name: "dbo.ClientServices", newName: "ServiceClients");
        }
    }
```

the migration tries to rename existing tables, and when I run it, it gives errno:2 no such file found error.

if I remove `public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` this line from Certificate model, the strange migration does not created.

Any ideas why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding collection navigation property to the principal entity of an existing relationship normally should not lead to migration because the database relationship is defined through FK column in the dependent table.

The problem is that EF mapping of many-to-many relations ship with implicit junction table is non deterministic. Since both involved tables have equal roles in the relationship, which one is considered *left" or "right" totally depends on the EF model dependency order algorithm, and the only requirement for that algorithm is to make sure the referenced tables are created before the dependent tables.

Shortly, adding navigation property can change the dependency graph ordering, thus the *left* and *right* roles in the implicit junction table for many-to-many relationships. Thus, you should not let EF choose them and always explicitly specify that via `HasMany` (left) / `WithMany` (right) fluent API.

To keep your original design, add the following to `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasMany(e => e.Clients).WithMany(e => e.Services);
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.Services).WithMany(e => e.Employees);
```